# Deserialization of hashmap in java

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

I am serializing a hash map in my Java code and write it to a file. While deserializing, the file contains more than one values, but it returns only top most key and value pair. Can anyone tell me why? Here is my Java code for deserialization:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("F:\\f.txt"));

    data = (HashMap<String, String>) in.readObject();

    for (Map.Entry entry : data.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key" + entry.getKey());
        System.out.println("value" + entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

Here is my serialization code

```
public class SerializeObject implements Serializable {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
             HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
             map.put("Monday","first");
             map.put("Tuesday","Second");
             map.put("Wednesday","Third");
             FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("F:\\f.txt",true);  
             ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);  
             out.writeObject(map);  
             out.flush();  

        }
  }
```

After deserializing it returns only Monday and first

Comment: What code are you using to serialize it? What are the contents of f.txt? Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Executing the deserialization after the serialization works fine... Also your map's key switches from String to Integer?!

Comment: Hi...sorry this is my mistake only

Answer (score 0):

You should close your streams. `out.flush()` might not be enough to ensure that all remaining data is written to disk. An easy way to ensure that is to use `try-with-resource` statements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
         HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
         map.put("Monday","first");
         map.put("Tuesday","Second");
         map.put("Wednesday","Third");
         try (
             FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("F:\\f.txt",true);  
             ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);  )
         {
            out.writeObject(map);  
         }
}
```